# Include subdirectories in url-pattern

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml, subdirectory, url-pattern

I would like to include every file contained in subdirectories of my jsp folder. Actually it's presented like that:

```
/WEB-INF/
    jsp/
        administration/
            products/
                list.jsp
                edit.jsp
            categories/
                list.jsp
                edit.jsp
```

I used this part of code to include header / footer on each, but it's working only for file on the administration folder, not all the subfolder.

```
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/administration/*</url-pattern>
    <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/assets/administration/header.jsp</include-prelude>
    <include-coda>/WEB-INF/assets/administration/footer.jsp</include-coda>
</jsp-property-group>
```

Is there a simple way to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to map that to all `*.jsp`?

```
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/assets/administration/header.jsp</include-prelude>
    <include-coda>/WEB-INF/assets/administration/footer.jsp</include-coda>
</jsp-property-group>
```